# Como Detecto o click no angular e passo a informação para o electron?

Tags: angular, electron

Estou trabalhando em uma aplicação Angular2 que executa junto ao Electron, preciso que ao clicar em um link específico do angular, a aplicação Electron finalize. Como faço esse tipo de comunicação, para que o Electron entenda um comando vindo do angular?

Comment: Adicone o seu código com um exemplo verificável do problema para que o comportamento possa ser reproduzido.

Comment: Não tenho tempo de postar uma resposta, mas se souber inglês, [leia este trecho do manual do electron](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-architecture).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você terá que usar o módulo ipcRenderer do Electron. Independente do framework JavaScript que você estiver usando a comunicação entre o navegador Chromiun e o Node no Electron é feita por envio de mensagem para os processos.

Então, o que acontece é o seguinte:

voce tem o Chromiun que é um navegador e tem o Node que é o backend de uma aplicação Electron. Se você quer pegar uma informação do navegador e manipular em seu main.js do Electron você precisa usar o ipcRenderer.

Vou te mostrar um exemplo, amigo:

Imagine que eu tenha um form e um botão e queira pegar o nome do arquivo selecionado por uma input do tipo file. Veja abaixo como eu teria que fazer no HTML de exibição da aplicação:

```
<script>
        const electron = require('electron');
        const {ipcRenderer} = electron;

        document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
           event.preventDefault();
           const {path} = document.querySelector('input').files[0];
           ipcRenderer.send('obterNomeArquivo', path);    
        });
</script>
```

Veja que o primeiro parâmetro do método **.send** do módulo ipcRenderer é o nome do identificador da sua mensagem. No seu main.js você pode pegar a informação da seguinte forma:

```
const {ipcMain} = electron;

ipcMain.on('obterNomeArquivo', (event, path)=> {
    console.log(path)
});
```

Espero ter te ajudado, amigo! Qualquer coisa só comunicar! Para finalizar, você pode ver a documentação do ipcRenderer, aqui:
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer